# CSS - The page becomes blank while showing or hiding a DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that can be called by clicking on a link named `Show / Hide search form` to Show or Hide a search form:

```
<script>
function hide_show_form_search() {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchform");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

The problem is that during the time that the page shows or hide the `DIV` called `searchform` the page becomes blank.

```
CODEPEN:
```

https://codepen.io/daniele0410/pen/ReRoPy

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please see how to create a  [mcve].  For example: what in the world are we supposed to do in your _massive_ codepen in order to trigger this activity?  Your codepen doesn't appear to include a function titled `hide_show_form_search`....

Comment: What does your event listener look like?

Comment: @cale_b i have edited the template at the minimum terms, the CSS is very long but since i am not an expert i don't know what part of the CSS is related at my question. What else can I do?

Comment: Truly, read the [mcve] article.  Focus on _minimal_.  You don't need all the HTML, you need NONE of the CSS, so boil it down to the minimal part it takes to recreate the problem.

Comment: @cale_b  , there is a link called `Show / Hide search form` at the top of the page just after the the navigation pages.

Comment: @Frish please explain better what i have to do and i will reply.

Comment: @Daniele how are you calling your javascript function, perhaps something like element.onClick, or <element onclick="">

Comment: @Frish - it's being called as `<a href="javascript: hide_show_form_search()">` - which is a big part of the problem, I believe....

Comment: @cale_b , I have replaced the code of the link with the following:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="hide_show_search_form();"` but the problem remains. Please note that this problem affects also when the page load for the first time, you can't see nothing until the page is FULLY loaded.

Comment: you are just missing a closing < / div tag.  you have < div class=page >  add a closing tag and it works fine

Comment: @DCR please tell me the line number where i have to add the colosing </div> tag.

Comment: line 44, on line 45 add the closing tag

Comment: here's your real problem <a href="javascript:void(0);"  just change that to a href='#'

Comment: It is easier for us to help you if you make the code you provide us concise. ~17,000 lines of CSS is hardly concise. As previously mentioned it isn't even really necessary for your problem. When producing a [MCVE], some times you have to start from scratch, just pulling out the parts you know you need, then slowly add more as required. This will also help build your skills in debugging. Remember when asking a question here, we need enough info *in the question itself*. We shouldn't have to go off site to find important info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can answer the question of why your whole page is disappearing when you click the show/hide link.

I can however propose an alternative solution:

Use `<span href='#' onclick="hide_show_search_form()" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor:pointer;">Show / Hide search form</span>` to call your hide/show function. [Here's some info on this usage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

Comment: I have replaced the code of the link with yours, the issue is fixed.

Comment: It's better not to use an A element as it infers navigation, and `href="#"` will likely scroll to the top of the page in many browsers. Consider using a button or span with similar styling (`text-decoration: underline; cursor:pointer` and so on) instead. ;-)

Comment: @RobG , i have added the following button, please let me know if it is the right procedure:

 `<button class="button button-xs button-primary button-icon button-icon-left button-anorak rd-navbar-popup-toggle" data-rd-navbar-toggle="#rd-navbar-search" onclick="hide_show_search_form()"><span class="icon mdi mdi-search-web"></span>Search</button>`